# How to create file names containing spaces when using brace expansion?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

If this command:

`touch Test{1..3}.txt`

Allows me to create:

- Test1.txt
- Test2.txt
- Test3.txt

What syntax would I need in order to batch create files containing a space in the file names?

For example:

- Test 1.txt
- Test 2.txt
- Test 3.txt

Obviously, I can create files with spaces *individually* with no problem just by using quotation marks (see below) but, for some reason, I don't seem to be able to do the same thing when using brace expansion:

`touch "Test 1.txt"`

So far, I have tried the following but with no success:

`touch "Test {1..3}.txt"`

Is there a problem with my syntax or is this just not possible with brace expansion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can try is something like:

```
touch Test\ {1..3}.txt
```

When other ways of escape char do not work back slash may work :)

Comment: It works!! I thought the solution would require quotation marks somewhere - very interesting!!

Answer (score 3):

Quote the space:

```
touch Test" "{1..3}.txt
touch Test' '{1..3}.txt
touch "Test "{1..3}.txt
touch 'Test '{1..3}.txt
touch Test\ {1..3}.txt
```

All the above work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for showing all the possible solutions!